# Bitwise and (&) operator

Tags: java, bit, operations

I read that doing a `& 0x7fffffff` masks just the sign bit and doesn't tampers with the other bits.

```
int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(a & 0x7fffffff);
```

But, this code outputs

```
0
```

instead of

```
2147483648
```

Why is that?

Comment: print `a` after your `SOP` statement.

Comment: Masking the sign bit doesn't mean you will get `-a`...

Comment: It prints '-2147483648'

Comment: print `~a` two's complements you will get what you want.

Comment: @Codebender, Here `a`  is negative number so masking the sign bit should `-a` . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user3824413, print the binary representation of a... `Integer.toBinaryString(a)`... That ll help you understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the most significant bit makes sure you get a non-negative value. It does not ensure that the result is positive. (0 is non-negative as well.) Neither does it make sure that you get the absolute value of the negative value. (Which you never get.)

Actually it will result in the following value for any negative `int` value: `negative_value - Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

For the reasoning why it behaves like this you have to check how the two's complement is working: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 5):

Negative numbers in Java are stored as twos complement. So a min value has sign bit set and all others not set.
So what you do is:

```
  10000000000000000000000000000000
& 01111111111111111111111111111111
```

When you clear the sign bit you get zero.

```
  00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @krzyk `int a = -25;
        System.out.println(a & 0x7fffffff);` prints `2147483623` . Shouldn't it print `25`?

Comment: @user3824413 No it shouldn't see my answer to the question.